# roxygen2 4.0.1 fails when man/figures is present

Tags: r, roxygen2

In an R package, I have a figure (jpeg) located under `man/figures`, which is added to a Rd file with,

`\if{html}{\figure{supplydemand.jpg}{Supply-demand}}
\if{latex}{\figure{supplydemand}{Supply-demand}}`

After updating to roxygen2 4.0.1, I get the error:

```
==> roxygen2::roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> first_time -> vapply -> FUN ->  readLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open file './man/figures': Permission denied
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

If I remove the code to insert the figure, I still get this error. Only when I remove the subdir `man/figures` does roxygen2 work OK.

I assume this is a bug in roxygen2 or is there a workaround?

Comment: This was also mentioned here:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rdevtools/QIsmPk_YL_U

Comment: Sounds like it might be a Windows issue. Sure enough, I just had no problems on a Mac.